# create a quad mesh over an image matlab

Tags: matlab, mesh

I am trying to implement this paper

```
    Patch based Image warping for Content aware Retargeting
```

I am half way through in its implementation in matlab, when  I came across the warping using quad mesh. The section III.c suggests me to formulate the image as a quad mesh with vertices, edges and quad faces. I have searched, but did not get the concrete result as to how to do this in matlab. Can you please tell me how to represent image as a quad mesh in matlab? Thanks in advance.

Update :

Pics from the paper stating the requirements better. Can you also please see the paper and tell me if am looking for the right thing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at triangulation techniques? What about Delaunay?  Also, take a look at these slides.  They're a good start.  There is also MATLAB code: http://image.diku.dk/kenny/download/vriphys10_course/meshing.pdf

Comment: @rayryeng thanks for the suggestion man. I think what I am looking for is basically splitting an image into equally spaced small rectangles or quads that covers as a mesh over the image. Can you tell me any function in matlab that can do that?

Comment: @rayryeng I read through the ppt, though I was not able to understand completely. But I felt what am looking for is actually simpler and maybe I dd not put it in right words. Sorry for asking again. please check the edit.

Comment: Yes... that's basically triangulation.  Vertex -> Pixels. Edges -> Weights connecting each pixel. Quad -> A set of vertices and edges to make a shape (triangle, square, rectangle).  Those slides I showed you basically will accomplish what you're asking.  In particular, slides 8-11.  The MATLAB code to do this is in the `.zip` file if you go here: http://image.diku.dk/kenny/download/vriphys10_course/.  Look at `make_particle_sampling` then `make_triangles`.

Comment: @rayryeng Thank you so much for your time. Do you mind if I can get your contact? Am implementing this paper and I feel you can be of real help. can you spend some time? my email : lakshmifull@gmail.com .